# Properly use NginX rewrite with PHP $_GET["query"], to echo the full URL (incl queries)

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location, request-uri

I would like to ECHO the full URL (incl queries) while also using the NginX rewrite (or request_uri, map). I have stire.php file that contains:

```
$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET["url"]);
echo $url;
```

In the NginX config I also have:

```
rewrite ^/stire-(.*)$ /stire.php?url=https://$1;
```

Visiting /stire.php?url=https://google.com and /stire-google.com I het the same echo:

```
https://google.com
```

**This is what I am trying to accomplish.**

**However**, if the URL contains queries itself, the ECHO does not write them when when I visit the rewritten URL. For example, /stire.php?url=https://google.com?a=1 will echo correctly:

```
https://google.com?a=1
```

...but /stire-google.com?a=1 will only echo:

```
https://google.com
```

therefore omitting the query a=1 (or any other following queries).

I've tried using if/request_uri is Nginx config, but ended up in endless loops. To keep this short, I won't write all my failures.

Please advise on what NginX config to use in order to achieve this purpose.